# Manual calculation of the covariance matrix is different from that of numpy method

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Given there is a matrix of `n` samples with `m` features, I am calculating the covariance matrix of features by hand so it should be `m` by `m`. That can be done by numpy, for small example,

```py
arr_x = np.array([[ 1,  4],
                  [ 4, 10],
                  [ 3,  6],
                  [ 5, 11],
                  [ 2,  4]])
print(np.cov(arr_x, rowvar=False)) 

>>> [[ 2.5  5. ]
     [ 5.  11. ]]
```

I can get the same covariance matrix by doing

```py
mean_x = np.mean(arr_x, 0)
np.dot(arr_x.T-mean_x[:, None],(arr_x.T-mean_x[:, None]).T)/(arr_x.shape[0] - 1)

>>> [[ 2.5,  5. ]
     [ 5. , 11. ]]
```

Yet, the latter derived method does not result in the same result as numpy for some what large matrix

```py
a = np.random.randint(0, 255, (5000, 200))
mean_a = np.mean(a, 0)
by_hand = np.dot(a.T-mean_a[:, None],(a.T-mean_a[:, None]).T)/(a.shape[0] - 1)
numpy_cov = np.cov(a, rowvar=False)
print((by_hand == numpy_cov).all())
```

What am I doing wrong or is there better way to get a covariance matrix by hand?

Comment: `np.abs((by_hand - numpy_cov)).mean()` gives `2.58e-16` so the difference is negligible.